# Check minimum CPU model

Tags: linux, cpu

Is there a way to check minimum version of CPU? We are supporting Ivy Bridge and newer, so I need to check for Ivy Bridge, Haswell, Skylake, etc.

Currently I use lscpu and matching the model name for each CPU meaning adding every configuration. There is also a model number which seems to increase with every new version, but I don't know if I can count on it.

So is there a way to do some sort of intelligent check for Ivy Bridge and newer CPU?

Comment: Does /proc/cpuinfo contain the information you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Years ago I had a similar discussion, and it was advised against such checks: numbers in CPU are not so useful (XEON and new families could have additional bits), additionally after some years Intel can releases (and do sometime) CPU of new families but stripped down with functionalities (e.g. for embedded devices).

So you should check for the special CPU features which are required by your code (the CPU flags), instead of families or models.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i needed to know. Now I'm checking the CPU flags and I can be sure that my code will work.